# Reading large result sets in jdbc

Tags: jdbc

I am using JDBC and have a Stored Procedure in DB2 which returns a huge amount of data - around 6000 rows. Because of this huge volume, network transfer (from db server to the application server) is taking time.

What I am thinking is to use multiple java threads to invoke the Stored Procedure with each thread returning different blocks of data.
Thread1 - row 1 - row 1000;
Thread2 - row 1001 - row 2000;
Thread3 - row 2001 - row 3000 and so on

All these threads can be run in parallel and I can aggregate the results of each thread.

Is there any better way to handle this problem using JDBC or any other means?

Comment: 6000 rows is not a huge amount of data. Multi-threading this won't improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your JDBC driver, [setting the fetch size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) may help. With the default fetch size of 0, your driver may be reading all rows into memory at once which could be the cause of the slowness.